# Create Dataframe from Column and Existing Data Frame (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe (A) with 10,000 rows and 1300(ish) columns.  I have a second data frame (B) with a single column, and 10,000 rows, numbered between 1 and 10,000 (not in order, no duplicates).

I'd like to use the 2nd (single column) data frame (B) to re-order the first data-frame (A) (i.e., if the first number in dataframe B is 7000, then the first row of the new dataframe (C) should be the 7000th row of Dataframe A.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
C = A[B[,1], ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dplyr` to `left_join` your 1st DF to your 2nd DF

e.g.

```
 df2 %>% left_join(df1, by = "id")
```

Note: This should theoretically work but I have not tested it.